# Android - get text values from a lot of edit texts

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is there any cleaner way to get the values from a bunch of edit texts other than doing:

```
val binding = MainActivityBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
val firstValue = binding.editText1.text.toString()
val secondValue = binding.editText2.text.toString()
val thirdValue = binding.editText3.text.toString() 
// and so on
```

?

Comment: How many text views are there?

Comment: Around 10, but there may come more.

Comment: add them all to an array, iterate over the array

Comment: Come more? How?

Comment: Maybe I need to add more. Depending on the structure of the data I want to save. Currently, there are 10, but if I want to store more details, I may need to add to them.

Comment: @a_local_nobody and how do I save each one of them in a variable that I want?

Comment: similarly, you can save those values into an array as well.

Comment: Creating `Array` is not a good way to approach it. You can check my answer. You can also use another Layout say `ConstraintLayout`

Comment: I don't think I can achieve 1 to 1 assignment with 2 for loops. Not easily, at least.

Answer (score 1):

```
fun getTextFrom(vararg editTexts: EditText): Map<Any, String> {
    return editTexts.map {
        it.tag to it.text.toString()
    }.toMap()
}
```

This will give you a map with the `tag` as the key and the `text` as the value. Just don't forget to add a tag to every `EditText` (`android:tag="1"`) so you know which tag or key belongs to what text.

This is what you would get if you pass in two `EditText`s, one with `tag=0` and `tag=1` :
`{0=hi, 1=hello}`

Answer (score -1):

Whatever the layout you'll use, i really suggest you to use ViewBinding and ViewModel from [Android Architecture components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture) to do this. You will have observable fields in a view model that will contain in real time all your editText values.

Using HaspHap<EditText, String?>

```
//+ setUp the hashMap with binding
fun setUpEditTextsMap() {
    this.mEditTexts = HashMap<EditText, String?>()
    editTexts[binding.editText1] = null
    editTexts[binding.editText2] = null
    ..
 }

 //+ setUp editTexts values when you want
 fun setUpEditTextValues() {
    mEditTexts.entries.forEach { it ->
        mEditTexts[it.key] = it.key.text?.toString()
    }
 }
```

this solution just simplify the way to init input edit text values.

Comment: I think this helps, but it does not solve the problem. I was wondering if there is any way to reduce the code and still keep it intuitive. If there is none, I still prefer the 1 by 1 assignment I started with.

Comment: You can have an array of EditText and get all the values in a loop. But the day you change on of the editText position you have to change your code and your tests if you have tests. Separate the view from the logic code in a viewModel is the most secure solution ;)

Comment: I know I can get the values in a for loop, but nothing comes in mind how can do a 1 to 1 assignment between a variable and a value in that loop. Like, I have to store n edit texts in n variables.

Comment: you can use a HaspMap<EditText, String>

Comment: this doesn't answer the question ?

Comment: I don't know. I'll have a look at what he says and see if it solves it. Still, can you write an example so I can have an idea how to do it?